# dbghelp.dll has a version mismatch with the debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have been getting the following error while trying to open the crash dump file in the WinDbg....
I am using 64bit version and having windows 7 OS.

versionof the WinDbg is 6.11

Error:

"dbghelp.dll has a version mismatch with the debugger."
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 AMD 64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
It says about the dbgeng and dbghelp, but in the message I see both versions are same.

And another popup comes on top of these error message which says
Failure when opeining dump file "file path" , HRESULT 0x80004005
It may be corrupt or in a format not understood by the debugger.
 Unspecified error.

Any help or suggestion would be helpful here.
Thanks

Comment: Clearly the 2nd message is caused by the 1st message.  Check that dbgeng.dll and dbghelp.dll are present in the same directory as windbg.exe and have the same time stamp.

Comment: yes, they are in the same directory and having the same timestamp.thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinDbg: Version mismatch of dbghelp.dll when trying to attach to a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882862/windbg-version-mismatch-of-dbghelp-dll-when-trying-to-attach-to-a-process)